# What is "/ 2.**15" doing in this line of code?

Tags: python, numpy, audio, wave

Here is the line of code:

```
    x = np.frombuffer(wave, np.int16)[24:] / 2.**15
```

My understanding is that I am filling a numpy array with data from the buffer. The data is categorized as wave of type int16 and will be handled by numpy in the appropriate manner. We are skipping 25 spaces before starting to take from buffer. I have no idea what the last part means "/ 2.**15"

Comment: `2.` is a floating point `2`. `**` is exponent. So its just `2^15 = 32768`.

Comment: so am I just dividing all cells of the numpy array by 32768?

Comment: Yes. It basically normalizes all cells so that they have a value between 0 and 1 since `int16` is between -32768 and +32767.

Comment: I am trying to better understand these concepts involved in creating an audio file from within python e.g. why are we normalizing all cells here. If you have any material I can read up or even a google search term that will get me on the right track, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Depends on the rest of your code really as to why you're normalising it. What are you doing with `x` later?

Comment: @Selcuk Isn't it between -1 and 1, not 0 and 1?

Comment: @Recessive Sorry, that's right.